# How to get the active file ID in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

So im currently using this to get the active file id of an add-on. However this only works on documents and not spreadsheets or forms. Anyone know a way around this?

```
 var files = DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());
```

Comment: please read the documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid  and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getid

Comment: That's not what I meant. I want to my add-on to be able to access all three. I dont want to have to specifically change DocumentApp to SpreadsheetApp. I have also read the documentation btw.

Comment: Try catch, or if else should work just fine. Seems like you want a one liner if possible, however I don't think it is. Just a few lines of code though.

Comment: So essentially onOpen check if its a doc form or spreadsheet and go from there? Is there a class that allows you to differentiate between the three of them?

Answer (score 5):

Try this out:

```
var id, ss, doc, form;

ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

if (ss != null && ss != undefined)
  id = ss.getId();
else if (doc != null && doc != undefined)
  id = doc.getId();
else if (form != null && form != undefined)
  id = form.getId();
```

I haven't had a chance to test this out yet, but I believe it'll work. If it throws errors on any of the lines trying to get the active docs, then nested try catches need to be used.

Answer (score -1):

For the `id` you can get it manually. In this sample web address,

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/samaladfajefjasdkfje/edit
```

in between `d/` and `/edit` is the `id`.

Another option is to make a container-bound script for each of the other files and write

```
function activeID()
{
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}
```

then run and press ctrl+enter ("View > Logs" if it does not work). Then, memorize the logged value.